# SQL Server 2017 - "Login failed for user" PHP on VirtualBox

Tags: php, sql-server

I wanna to connect with my database which is hosted on Virtual Machine (VB with Win 8.1). Connection attempt tested by Microsoft Data Link on main machine, returns successful connection but my localhost always display a message:

```
            [0] => 28000
            [SQLSTATE] => 28000
            [1] => 18456
            [code] => 18456
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'.
```

For user with 'Enforce password policy' enabled I got:

```
            [0] => 28000
            [SQLSTATE] => 28000
            [1] => 18488
            [code] => 18488
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'userDB2'.  Reason: The password of the account must be changed.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'userDB2'.  Reason: The password of the account must be changed.
```

Same code working fine on VM localhost. In both cases, PHP 7.4 is used (with the latest drivers from https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql).

Server Authentication settings (VM):
[image: Server Authentication settings]

Script used:

```php
$server = '127.0.0.1';
$cinfo = array(
    "Database"=>'mydbname',
    "UID"=>'sa',
    "PWD"=>'root'
);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);

if ($conn === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

Firewall on VM is disabled.

TCP/IP protocol in SQL Server Configuration is enabled.

Port forwarding in VirtualBox settings:

[image: VM Network settings]

I tried to use different users with different settings but always this errors appears.

UPDATE:
Last SQL Logs
[image]

Comment: You showed that you have failed logins only logged, but did you actually check said logs and check to see if the failed connections are in there? If not, you should and then let us know what you find.

Comment: _"Reason: The password of the account must be changed"_ - Have you tried changing it? It's literally telling you what the reason is and what you should do to to resolve it.

Comment: Yes, as i said - i used many users with different settings.